# This JavaScript snippet appears to not strip out Unicode escape characters in JavaScript - why?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I was testing this snippet in my browser and with some online JavaScript testers:

```
var s = "testing \u0123 one two three";
s = s.replace(/\u[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]/g,'');
alert (s);
```

I would expect the result in alert to be just "testing one two three" but a funny character appears where the \u0123 is.

My question is why doesn't the replace strip that out?

I know it's not the most elegant regular expression. But isn't it correct? I'm stripping out the backlash character followed by exactly 4 hexidecimal characters. Or trying to anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why doesn't the replace strip that out?

Because the `/\u[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]/g` regular expression literally matches a `\u` string followed by 4 hexadecimal characters.

Whereas `\u0123` being specified in a string literal is treated as a codepoint on the parsing step, so in the string in run time there is no `\u0123` there but 2 physical bytes of UTF-16.

What you actually want instead is something like `[\u0080-\uFFFF`]:

```
> "testing \u0123 one two three".replace(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]/g, '')
"testing  one two three"
```

This character set specifies all the codepoints that does not fall into ASCII space.

> In string literals, regular expression literals, and identifiers, any character (code unit) may also be expressed as a Unicode escape sequence consisting of six characters, namely \u plus four hexadecimal digits.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point
- http://es5.github.io/#x6

Comment: Another thing, your regex doesn't work as you expect, since JS is stuck processing string as UCS-2. (Well, I don't think there is any function in JS string that actually operates on UTF-16 code point). The earlier solution with `\uFFFF` works, since it also covers the surrogate code units.

Comment: @nhahtdh oh, I need to stop trusting MDN anymore, it states "The Unicode escape sequences require at least four characters following \u."

Comment: Interesting. The string appears in some JSON I'm retrieving. At least that's what it looks like in BBEdit. I did try your expression though and it worked, so I guess it's safer to use yours. Thanks.

Comment: @nhahtdh do you have any ideas how to match the characters beyond that? (see my updates, and thanks for your contribution)

Comment: @zerkms: The regex as it is works. The surrogates (`\ud800-\udc00`) are stripped by `[\u0080-\uFFFF]` since JS operates on UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: @nhahtdh right, for the Unicode codepoint after `0xFFFF` both UTF-16 surrogate pairs will be `> 0x0080`, thanks again

Comment: You might want to read about the hairy details about this on mathias's site: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding

Comment: One more dumb question. Why not go ahead and make the range [\u0000-\uFFFF] instead of starting with 0080?

Comment: @Doug Lerner: because every character falls into that range. Literally every.

Comment: @zerkm - Thanks. Interestingly, my initial solution works in my server side script in stripping out unwanted \unnnn characters. But your solution, which works on the client side, leaves the unwanted characters in if I try it in my server side script. It's too complicated for my mind, I think, but maybe what I think I'm seeing in the JSON string representation must not be what's "really there" in the string. Maybe they are escaped characters and so my replace works? The reason I posted the question is because I tested my solution on the client-side and saw it didn't work so was curious.

Comment: @DougLerner not sure what I can add here. That regular expression does what I explained - it strips out the characters with the given codes. If it does not remove something - then that "something" is in the "valid" ASCII codes range. Or you need to explain what "unwanted character" exactly means with example. As of JSON - it may contain literally the `\uXXXX` literal sequence, as a part of the string, and you **SHOULD NOT** process the raw JSON string. After your JSON parser does its job the characters will be parsed and removed with this regex.

Comment: No need to add anything. You were very instructive! You must be right that the JSON contains the literal  `uXXXX` sequence, and that's the reason. I don't know what you mean by not processing the raw JSON though. What I'm doing is converting the JSON to an object and using the object. However, there are some characters in the JSON (coming through from an external API) which were causing invalid utf-8 characters to be created in my object, which I then exported as XML and the XML wasn't validating. But by stripping out the few weird characters before converting to an object all seems well.

Comment: @DougLerner "I don't know what you mean by not processing the raw JSON though." --- I mean that the `\uXXXX` literal in JSON string exists only before the JSON string was parsed. After it was - it's a parser job to substitute it with the actual character. So I highly recommend you to not apply any string functions to the raw JSON string as it may potentially damage its structure. But in your case that might be necessary though, as you say they are broken initially.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76358/discussion-between-doug-lerner-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with some small modifications as is:

```
var s = "testing \\u0123 one two three"; // (1)
s = s.replace(/\\u[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]/g,''); // (2)
alert (s);
```

1. Escape the "\" in the string.
2. Escape the "\" character in the Regex.